# Creating a Hotkey in Java

Tags: java, key, bind, key-bindings, hotkeys

I've been playing around with automation in java, since it's cross platform, kind of trying to create an autoit alternative for linux. Anyways I have this script working great, **but I just want to be able to toggle an action with a hotkey.**

I've seen the docs for key binding (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), but either it isn't quite what I'm after or I'm misunderstanding the docs, in which case please forgive me and point me in the right direction.

My problem is that I don't have an GUI running, I have a java program that is moving my mouse to a new random position every 3 seconds. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] screen = ScreenGetDim(); //get screen dimentions
        while (1==1) {
            int[] coordinates = new int[2]; //create an array for X and Y screen coordinates
            coordinates[0] = IntGetRandom( 0, screen[0] ); //get random X coordinate on screen
            coordinates[1] = IntGetRandom( 0, screen[1] ); //get random Y coordinate on screen
            MouseMove(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]); //move the mouse to screen coordinates
            Sleep(3000); //wait 3 seconds
        }
    }
```

This script works just like it should (*ScreenGetDim()*, *IntGetRandom()*, *MouseMove()*, and *Sleep()* are all functions that work perfectly and that I've defined elsewhere in the code).

**My goal here is to be able to create a hotkey that could do something when I press it at any point during the runtime of my program.**

For example, if I could set F11 as a hotkey that would do `System.out.println("You pressed F11");` every time I press it that would be great. **In AutoIt, for instance, one would just create a function that would do whatever you wanted to, let's call it *Action()*, and then you could simply do `HotKeySet("{F11}", "Action")` to make *Action()* run anytime you press F11. I'm looking for a Java equivalent.**

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Basically all of Java is set up to be in a GUI. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for event handling. You need to implement the interface KeyListener, this lets you create functions that get called whenever you press a button the function will look like this

```
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
         //TODO list of all KeyCodes of events and code you want to execute(F11 keycode = 122)
         }
         }
```

after that you need to set the KeyListener to Listen to your Interface, Here it might get a bit tricky to help you since I don't know what kind of GUI you are using. When i used KeyListeners I used a Canvas, if you are using that it would look like this

```
        canvas.addKeyListener(this);
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Sweet, this is more or less exactly what I'm looking for, I'm only curious as to how I could implement this when I don't have a GUI at all? Is it even possible?

If not could I perhaps have a 1 pixel x 1 pixel transparent GUI running just to capture KeyEvents? Thanks for your answer! I'll play around and see if I can make it work.

Comment: What i am saying here is guesswork, but it could be possible that you create a canvas, but don't put on the Frame/Label which might make your canvas listen to events but not actually be vissible, creating a canvas of 1x1 should be possible but java will allways create the top bar with the pictograms to close maximalize and minimalize buttons i Think im kind of busy so I can't go into more detail or put some time into research